# How do I keep images in place as the browser is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello on my page i have 2 character images, that i have placed on both sides of a text and banner, heres a picture of it https://i.stack.imgur.com/z65bg.jpg but heres the problem, when i rezise my browser the images follows with the browser, they do not stay in the same position, and i dont want this to happen because i have a fixed layout, heres the css code, i dont know how to post it good, but anyway

```
.support-text {
  width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    line-height: -2px;
    margin-bottom: 130px;

}

.support-text h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.support-text {
  clear: left;
}

.support-text {
  font-size: 23px;
}

.support-img {
  margin-top: -80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ct-pic {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 30px;
  float: right;
}

.ct-pic:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(180%);
}

.t-pic:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(180%);
}

.t-pic {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  bottom: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

heres the html

```
<section class="support-text">
          <div class="ct-pic"> </div>
     <div class="t-pic" width="867" height="569"></div>
      <img src="img/support-us.png" class="support-img">
      <p>Hello, if this site has helped you improve your gameplay, and learn useful stuff, feel free to support us, so we can keep this website up, so more people can learn. You can support through Steam or throught paypal. Keep in mind that you do not have to support, but if you do, we appreciate it alot. and we can continue to upload new content (Smokes, flashes, tactics) to the website. </p>

    </section>
```

Comment: you need to include your html as well and any javascript.

Comment: don't use an image `<img>`, use a `div` with a `background` set as the image link and give it a fixed width

Comment: We're gonna need to see the html as well but you can't float **and** position something absolutely...pick one or the other.

Comment: you can do some testing at http://dragndesign.com and look at the generated code to see which one you want to use

Comment: heres a fiddle to demonstrate your options http://jsfiddle.net/7qytj718/ resize the fiddle width to see how the image changes

Comment: i added the html code

Comment: i do not want the images to change when i rezise i want the mthe same as size all the time, and at the same position

Answer (score 0):

heres an example of how to position things next to each other without them moving away or changing positions when you resize the window (the divs can be img tags or whatever you want them to be). Just put them in a "container" with a  fixed width, and then float them inside that container

```
<div id='container'> 
    <div id='image-1' class='image'></div>
    <div id='image-2' class='image'></div>
    <div id='image-3' class='image'></div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
}
.image {
    background: white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7qytj718/1/

***update***

you have an issue with your css. You're setting child elements' positions to absolute, this makes them ignore their parent element and become positioned relative to the entire window. When this happens, the child elements start moving when the window is resized.

Comment: i have them inside a container with a fixed with

Comment: your problem is your children divs have a `position:absolute` which makes them position relative to the window, not their parent div. You need to remove the `position:absolute` and either use floats or use `position:relative`